# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined aftering trying to do POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

This error pops up in browser when trying to post: 
newest error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at SandwhichForm.js:30
    at async SandwhichForm.handleFormSubmit (SandwhichForm.js:27)

Here is the full code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import axios from 'axios';

    const FormItem = Form.Item;


    class SandwhichForm extends React.Component {

        handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, sandwhichID) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const postObj = {
                title: event.target.elements.title.value,
                content: event.target.elements.content.value
            }   

        axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
        axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
        axios.defaults.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
        };

        if (requestType === "post") {
            await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_sandwhiches/create/', postObj)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 201) {
                        this.props.history.push(`/`);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        } else if (requestType === "put") {
            await axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_sandwhiches/${sandwhichID}/update/`, postObj)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        this.props.history.push(`/`);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
            }
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Form 
                        onSubmit={event => 
                            this.handleFormSubmit(
                                event,
                                this.props.requestType,
                                this.props.sandwhichID
                            )
                        }
                    >
                        <FormItem label="Title">
                            <Input name = "title" placeholder="Put a title here" />
                        </FormItem>
                        <FormItem label="Content">
                            <Input name="content" placeholder="Enter some content ..." />
                        </FormItem>
                        <FormItem >
                            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                                {this.props.btnText}
                            </Button>
                        </FormItem>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            token: state.token
        };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SandwhichForm)
```

What is happening:

1. Information was posting and going to api
2. error now in console not browser
3. info is no longer posting

Comment: how is `handleFormSubmit` looks like, maybe it isnt binded or something like that?

Comment: class SandwhichForm extends React.Component {
    handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, sandwhichID) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const postObj = {
            title: event.target.elements.title.value,
            content: event.target.elements.content.value
        }

    if (requestType === "post") {
        await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_sandwhiches/create/', postObj)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    this.props.history.push('/api_sandwhiches/');
                }
            })

Comment: I am unsure what to bind it to?

Comment: `handleFormSubmit = async (event, requestType, sandwhichID) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const postObj = {
            title: event.target.elements.title.value,
            content: event.target.elements.content.value
        } `

Comment: It looks like you are using arrow function so it shouldn't be binded,  but will be helpful if you just edit your answer and paste the code there. Unfortunately it is almost unreadable here

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez that wasnt the answer that was what my code looks like

Comment: Sorry instead of answer i should said in your main post, sorry for the @John Gartsu mistake

Comment: Where are you defining `this.props.history`? Is your component being rendered as a child of a router? In that case, what router are you using and what is your render hierarchy?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez thank you for the clarification. I will edit it now!

Comment: @mgarcia I am posting it at the "post" and "put" request .then() ... I am using BrowserRouter. Then its browserRouter, router, routerProvider for the hierarchy

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I think the error was trying to inform me about not dealing with the rejection promise. So I added .catch(error). Now the error isnt in browser but console, and is updating the page at all. I have posted lasted version of code as well.

Comment: @mgarcia I think the error was trying to inform me about not dealing with the rejection promise. So I added .catch(error). Now the error isnt in browser but console, and is updating the page at all. I have posted lasted version of code as wel

Comment: @Jawi will i still be able to maintain the same functionality?

Comment: @Jawi the browser is now telling me handleFormSubmit is undefined